# C/C++ Static Analysis - Tool to show header used in statement or line

Tags: c++, c, dependencies, static-analysis

I'm searching for a tool to get the used header (if there is one/more) for every line/statment in my c++ code.

Example:

```
#include<iostream> 
std::cout << "hallo";
```

The output i'd like to see:

> line 2: std::cout uses "iostream"

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies) question, the tools there do most of the part, they show dependency per file.

Does anyone know such a tool or how to acomplish this with the tools given in the answers in [the question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308/tool-to-track-include-dependencies)?

Goal: I'm checking code for the conformity to a standard which i have a list of allowed headers for. With the desired output I can create a metric saying something like: **60% of the code is using allowed headers, 15% is using other headers** or something like that.

Comment: If all you want is a metric saying "this file uses unallowed headers", why do you need a line-by-line analysis?  (I say that because tracking lines through name resolution is a fair amount of work, if you already have a working C++ name resolver)

Comment: Another way is simply to remove/rename the forbidden files and se where the build falls over :-)  Did you find a tool to do what you ask? I would like that too

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) to get all the methods called by a specific one with the location of each method called.

[image]

Comment: From $99 per seat